Terminology for eigenvalue degeneracy with geometric multiplicity 1
When there is an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity two but geometric multiplicity one, can we say that there is an eigenvalue degeneracy?
For a concrete example, consider the following example
Puzzling eigenvector degeneracy

An eigenvalue with a geometric multiplicity that is smaller than its algebraic multiplicity is called defective eigenvalue.
A matrix, which does not have a complete eigenvector basis (defective eigenvalues, characteristic polynomial cannot be written as product of linear factors in the underlying field but contains irreducible factors of higher degree), is called defective matrix.
There is no special term for the special case in which the algebraic multiplicity is $2$ and the geometric multiplicity is $1$.
